# BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http' or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, shared-hosting, webapi

I host Asp.net Web API (C#) project in my shared hosting server. but it gives me following error.

can you please check and how to resolved this issue. Is there any setting in Web.API side while publishing.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

> *“System.BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a reference assembly for execution”* error:
> *BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Extensions' or one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution...*

***Solution:*** Delete the bin folder and rebuild the project.